# Not sure how to fix the warnings I am getting

Tags: c, struct

I am trying to pass a struct through parameters and I am having trouble fixing the warnings I am getting.  I wrote a small piece of stand alone code the produces the warning messages I was getting on a larger piece of code.  The problem seems to be that I have the wrong parameters for start_thread.  What do I do to fix them?

These are the three warnings I am getting.

> ‘struct port_t’ declared inside parameter list [enabled by default]
>
> its scope is only this definition or declaration, which is probably
>   not what you want [enabled by default]
>
> passing argument 2 of ‘start_thread’ from incompatible pointer type
>   [enabled by default]

Here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define N 10

typedef struct {
    int port[N];
    int id;
} port_t;


void createPort(port_t *temp, int id)
{

    temp->port[0] = 0;
    temp->port[1] = 1;
    temp->port[2] = 2;
    temp->port[3] = 3;
    temp->port[4] = 4;
    temp->port[5] = 5;
    temp->port[6] = 6;
    temp->port[7] = 7;
    temp->port[8] = 8;
    temp->port[9] = 9;
    temp->id = id;

}


void send(port_t temp)
{

}

void start_thread(void *function, struct port_t *port)
{
    printf("In main: creating thread\n");

}



int main(void) {

    port_t id[100];

        int x;
        for(x =0; x < 100; x++)
        {
            createPort(&id[x], x);
        }

        start_thread(send, &id[0]);
    puts("!!!Hello World!!!"); /* prints !!!Hello World!!! */
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: `port_t` (w/o "struct") is a typedef to an *unnamed* struct.  `struct port_t` is something else, probably not defined.  If you'd done `typedef struct port_t { int port[N]; int id; } port_t;` instead, then they'd be compatible (as you'd have a struct named "port_t" as well as the typedef).

Answer (score 2):

Take the "struct" out of the `start_thread` definition.  You've already declared a `typedef` of a `port_t` above as a pointer to the specified structure, and that's the type you seem to mean to use.

`struct` is for defining a new structure type, one you already have.